Adding keyboard language in intune to AVD
I have an AVD and I'm trying too add a language to the keyboard for the users in intune.
I tried creating a platform script and remediation script but it didn't gave me what i wanted to add a language to the keyboard for a user that logged into the avd, is there a policy or something I can do to add it to the keyboard of a the user.
I know how to do it in a gpo like adding a policy that add a registry value of the wanted language, but how to do it in intune

you can use Intune's Remediation script feature to deploy a script that will add the language. For more details on the actual script, check out this similar question: How to set only keyboard language / layout in Windows 10?
You can deploy this as a Remediation script. For more info, refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/remediations
Feel free to add a comment if this doesn't help!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
